# Random sampling from a stream of unknown length

Tags: statistics, probability

Say I need to randomly sample K elements from a real-time stream of N>>K elements where I have only finite memory, and where I don’t know N in advance. Can there be an algorithm for this that would be theoretically sound, i.e., comply with the technical meaning of taking a random sample from a collection?

I know there can be an algorithm for this that would satisfy some intuitions about random sampling, but the question is, is it formally sound?

In other words, how can I prove that an algorithm I come up with indeed produces a random sample in such a setting?

For example, if I can prove that my algorithm produces K elements where each element out of the stream was included with a probability of K/N – is that a legitimate proof?

Comment: Do you want to sample uniformly or is it okay if elements are sampled with different probability?

Comment: I want to take a "simple random sample" (uniformly).

Answer (score 3):

There exist algorithms for that, see the [Wikipedia article on reservoir sampling](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Yes, you'd need to show that your samples have uniform probability (and you'll probably want them to be independent too). That's exactly what the proof of Algorithm R in the linked page does.

Comment: My question was not on finding the algorithm, but a meta-theoretical question on whether it is possible to formally prove that an algorithm for such setting indeed produces a random sample.

Comment: It does answer your first question, on whether there can be such an algorithm. I updated it to address the other point.

Comment: Donald Knuth's 2nd book has the answer to this somewhere around page 120-170. I believe the correctness can be proved by mathematical induction, but I'm not sure whether Knuth provides a proof. I believe he does. I do not have a copy of my Knuth books with me.

Answer (score 0):

We need sample k elements.

1. For the first k data from stream (1th to kth), we will keep it.
2. for the following ith element (i>k), we will have some probability p to choose it or not. Also when we choose to keep the new ith element, we need to kick out one element from the previous k data. Then we have the following formula:

$k/i (1-p/k)=p$

explain: left size, k/i the the probability for first i element from the stream. (1-p/k) is the probability each element will not be kick out. So, the multiplication will represent the probability each element (from 1th to ith) will be stored, and this should be equal to p, which is the probability we keep i+1 th element.

After solve this equation, we get p=k/(1+N), which is the probability we will keep the new coming data. and 1/1+N is the probability we will kick out the data in original k.

Comment: That will give a uniform sampling of the buffer, not of the K elements.